# MockHttpServletResponse is not returning mocked list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

I'm trying to test a simple controller mocking the service results. For that I'm using `when().thenReturn()` method of Mockito returning a new array. It does work for asserting the OK status and the returning array size, the problem is that the objects inside that array are empty, so I can't assert them to have some value.

Specifically the `MockHttpServletResponse` response body is `[{},{},{}]` and the assertion error `java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$[0].id"`.

This is a really basic case, but I will need to do some transformations at the returning array from the service, so I need their values to be mocked in order to test them.

Is it possible to mock them? What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Here is the code for the test:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(BookController.class)
public class BookControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private BookService bookService;

    @Test
    void getAllBooks() throws Exception {
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
        books.add(new Book(1L, "Book 1", "Author 1", "Description 1"));
        books.add(new Book(2L, "Book 2", "Author 2", "Description 2"));
        books.add(new Book(3L, "Book 3", "Author 3", "Description 3"));
        when(bookService.getAllBooks()).thenReturn(books);

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(Urls.BOOK_URL)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(3)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].id").value(1L));
    }
}
```

The actual controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(Urls.BOOK_URL)
public class BookController {

    private final BookService bookService;

    public BookController(BookService bookService) {
        this.bookService = bookService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Book> getAllBooks() {
        return bookService.getAllBooks();
    }

}
```

And the basic entity:

```java
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String description;
}
```

Comment: There are no getters/setters in your entity so no values will be in the json. You need `@Getters` and `@Setters` as well to generate those.

Comment: It was that, I've been trying to fix the problem for hours and I didn't realize I didn't have them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually does return your list, which is apparent by the assertion of size 3 not failing. The problem is your `Book` class doesn't have getters and setters and those (or at least the getters) are needed to create JSON.

As you are using Lombok add `@Getters` and `@Setters` to the class to generate those.